# Raycasting with maximum distance

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm writing a simple raycast in htm5l and the main issue with the raycast is that the line goes off in a direction of probably infinite length.. I would like to limit that length to a specific radius but I'm not having any luck. If someone could guide me that'd be great.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  let coord = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  }

  function line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  class Vector {
    constructor(x, y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
  }
  class Boundery {
    constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      this.a = new Vector(x1, y1);
      this.b = new Vector(x2, y2);
    }
    show() {
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000'
      line(this.a.x, this.a.y, this.b.x, this.b.y);
    }
  }
  class Ray {
    constructor(x, y) {
      this.pos = new Vector(x, y);
      this.dir = new Vector(Math.cos(1), Math.sin(0));

    }

    show() {
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, 5, 5, 0, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.stroke();

    }

    cast(wall) {
      let x1 = wall.a.x;
      let y1 = wall.a.y;
      let x2 = wall.b.x;
      let y2 = wall.b.y;

      let x3 = this.pos.x;
      let y3 = this.pos.y;
      let x4 = this.pos.x + this.dir.x;
      let y4 = this.pos.y + this.dir.y;

      let den = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4);
      if (den == 0) {
        return;
      }
      let t = ((x1 - x3) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y3) * (x3 - x4)) / den;
      let u = -((x1 - x2) * (y1 - y3) - (y1 - y2) * (x1 - x3)) / den;

      if (t > 0 && t < 1 && u > 0) {
        let point = new Vector(x1 + t * (x2 - x1), y1 + t * (y2 - y1));
        return point;

      } else {
        return;
      }
    }

  }

  let wall = new Boundery(300, 100, 300, 300);
  let ray = new Ray(100, 200);

  function tick(timestamp) {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
    wall.show();
    ray.show();
    let r = ray.cast(wall);
    if (r) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
      ctx.ellipse(r.x, r.y, 10, 10, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fill();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

So the ray currently fires to the right (1,0) of the small red circle but it's distance just goes on forever so I'm trying to limit that distance. In the example the position the ray hits the wall is the red circle that's drawn on the wall

Comment: ?? `this.dir = new Vector(Math.cos(1), Math.sin(0));` makes no sense,  did you mean  `this.dir = new Vector(Math.cos(0), Math.sin(0));` .All rays are Infinite, Are you asking how to get length of the line segment from `ray.pos` (small circle) to `r` (larger circle)?  `length = Math.hypot(r.x -ray.pos.x, r.y - ray.pos.y)`

Comment: No what I'm trying to do is limit the length of the ray. So maybe getting the length of the line segment is the same thing? I'm not sure. And the above code was supposed to be `Math.sin(1),Math.cos(0)`

Comment: `(sin(1), cos(0))` is not a unit vector while `cos(0), sin(0)` is a Unit vector (has a length equal to 1) as is  `cos(n), sin(n)` where n is any value representing a bearing in radians or `d` degrees  `cos(d / 180 * PI), sin(d / 180 * PI)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ray length and direction

Modify the ray to have the start position, a direction, and a length. as follows

```
class Ray {
    constructor(pos, direction, length) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.dir = direction;
        this.length = length;
    }
```

You can get the end point with

```
    get end() {
        return new Vector(
            this.pos.x + Math.cos(this.dir) * this.length,
            this.pos.y + Math.sin(this.dir) * this.length
        );
    }
```

When you `cast` the ray you convert the ray to a line segment and then check against any wall segments for the intercept. Only points withing the length of the ray will be found.

### Example.

The example uses a ray to check against many walls. It finds the closest intercept to the  to the start of the ray and within the rays length.

**Note** (FOR example only) the walls are random so if a wall gets to close to the ray, click the canvas to randomize the walls.

I have re-organised it somewhat with `Vector` as a point, `Line` (2 vectors) as a line segment with an intercept function (also represents a wall), And `Ray` as a vector, direction and length. The `Ray.cast` finds the intercept of an array of line, returning undefined if no intercept found.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
var myRay;
const WALL_COUNT = 30;
const WALL_STYLE = {radius: 0, lineWidth: 1, strokeStyle: "#000"};
const RAY_STYLE_A = {radius: 2, lineWidth: 1, strokeStyle: "#0FF", fillStyle: "#F00"};
const RAY_STYLE_B = {radius: 5, lineWidth: 3, strokeStyle: "#00F", fillStyle: "#F00"};
const RAY_INTERCEPT_STYLE = {radius: 5, lineWidth: 1, strokeStyle: "#000", fillStyle: "#FF0"};
const ROTATE_RAY = 10; // seconds per rotation
const walls = [];
setTimeout(init, 0);
canvas.addEventListener("click",init);

class Vector {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    draw(ctx, {radius = 5, lineWidth = 2, strokeStyle = "#000", fillStyle = "#F00"} = {}) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
        ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, radius, 0, Math.TAU);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();       
    }
}
class Line {
    constructor(start, end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    draw(ctx, {radius = 5, lineWidth = 2, strokeStyle = "#000", fillStyle = "#F00"} = {}) {
        if (radius > 0) {
            this.start.draw(ctx, {radius, lineWidth, strokeStyle, fillStyle});
            this.end.draw(ctx, {radius, lineWidth, strokeStyle, fillStyle});
        }
        ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.start.x, this.start.y);
        ctx.lineTo(this.end.x, this.end.y);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    intercept(line) {
        var x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, c, u;
        x1 = line.end.x - line.start.x;
        y1 = line.end.y - line.start.y;
        x2 = this.end.x - this.start.x;
        y2 = this.end.y - this.start.y;
        c = x1 * y2 - y1 * x2;
        if (c) {
            x3 = line.start.x - this.start.x;
            y3 = line.start.y - this.start.y;
            u = (x1 * y3 - y1 * x3) / c;
            if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
                u = (x2 * y3 - y2 *x3) / c;
                if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) { return [u, line.start.x + x1 * u, line.start.y + y1 * u]  }
            }
        }
    }
}
class Ray {
    constructor(pos, direction, length) {
        this.pos = pos;
        this.dir = direction;
        this.length = length;
    }

    draw(ctx, {radius = 5, lineWidth = 2, strokeStyle = "#000", fillStyle = "#F00"} = {}) {
        this.pos.draw(ctx, {radius, lineWidth, strokeStyle, fillStyle});
        ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
        ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(
            this.pos.x + Math.cos(this.dir) * this.length,
            this.pos.y + Math.sin(this.dir) * this.length
        );
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    get end() {
        return new Vector(
            this.pos.x + Math.cos(this.dir) * this.length,
            this.pos.y + Math.sin(this.dir) * this.length
        );
    }
    get line() {
        return new Line(this.pos, this.end);
    }
    cast(lines) {
        const tLine = this.line;
        var minDist = 1, point;
        for (const line of lines) {
            const result = line.intercept(tLine);
            if (result) {
                const [u, x, y] = result;
                if (u <= minDist) {
                    minDist = u;
                    if (!point) { point = new Vector(x, y) }
                    else { 
                        point.x = x;
                        point.y = y;
                    }
                     point.u = u;
                }
            }
        }
        return point;
    }
}


function init() {
    walls.length = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < WALL_COUNT / 2; i++) {
        walls.push(new Ray(
          new Vector(Math.rand(0, canvas.width * 0.4), Math.rand(0, canvas.height)),
          (Math.rand(0, 8) | 0) / 4 * Math.PI, 100
        ).line);
        walls.push(new Ray(
          new Vector(Math.rand(canvas.width * 0.6, canvas.width), Math.rand(0, canvas.height)),
          (Math.rand(0, 8) | 0) / 4 * Math.PI, 100
        ).line);
    }
    if(!myRay) {
        myRay = new Ray(new Vector(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2), 0, Math.max(canvas.width, canvas.height) * 0.485);    
        requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    }
        
}

function mainLoop(time) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    myRay.dir = (time / (ROTATE_RAY * 1000)) * Math.TAU;
    const point = myRay.cast(walls)
    myRay.draw(ctx, RAY_STYLE_A);
    for(const w of walls) { w.draw(ctx, WALL_STYLE) }
    if (point) {
        const len = myRay.length;
        myRay.length = point.u * len;
        myRay.draw(ctx, RAY_STYLE_B);
        myRay.length = len;
        point.draw(ctx, RAY_INTERCEPT_STYLE);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">  </canvas>
```